# Defining a relative runtime folder

Tags: visual-studio, directory, compilation

I'm developing a program to adjust the color of a connected lamp according to our activity in a virtuel phone system. (Talking on the phone = Red, Available = Green, White = Lunchtime and so on and so forth...)

I'm almost done and the programs is running smoothly on my PC.(The same PC as I developed it on.)
The trouble comes when I try to run it from another PC. When I do, it seems that program still thinks it's running in the folder I compiled it in and NOT the local folder I run the program in.

I've implemented log4net and the very first line in the log contains process that initialted the log entry(%logger)...
When I run it the first line reads:

13:10:26,790 [C:\Users\TROL0010\source\repos\LightMyWork\LightMyWork\Program.cs] INFO - ---------------------  Program starting

--- but this does not seem right.... This is the folder I used to develop the software, but it is NOT the folder I run the program from...
I'm running the program from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LightMyWork'.

I suspect a simple setting in Visual Studio, but I have been unable to find it. Searching for relative runtime folders/directories or sim, has not been successful...

Have any of you expirenced the same?
I've been unable to find af solution anywhere...

Comment: Please, provide code where you initiate logger. It seems, you have a string constant in your code to initiate log path, because you don't use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to retrieve current folder, where executable was started

Comment: Hi Maxim,
Thank you for the reply.

My contructor for the log4Net is as follows:

    public class LogHelper // Denne klasse bruges til log
    {
        public static log4net.ILog GetLogger([CallerFilePath]string filename = "")
        {
            return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filename);
        }
    }

I define the log4net in the 'programs.cs' as follows:

Comment: public class SuiteApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); //LogHelper.GetLogger();
        NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        LampRestBroker broker = new LampRestBroker();
...
}

The first time I use it is in my 'static main method :
log.Info("---------------------  Program starting  ---------------------");

Comment: The log for this seems to be the line listet above:
13:10:26,790 [C:\Users\TROL0010\source\repos\LightMyWork\LightMyWork\Program.cs] INFO - --------------------- Program starting----------------


Was this the code you where asking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, Your code in comments not readable. You should edit your post and add code there.